# How to run gnome-terminal -- 'npm run start' without the error 'Permission denied'?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, permissions

In a bash script, my command `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/my/working/folder -- 'npm run start'` gives me the error `Failed to execute child process “npm run start” (Permission denied)`

Similar commands such as  `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/my/working/folder -- '/some_file.sh'` work fine.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: How did you install npm? If it was something like `sudo apt install npm`, then the package manager can only run with `sudo` (or by changing a lot of permissions to `777`, which is generally not ideal) 

Comment: Ah, right. npm came preinstalled on our work laptops, we have no sudo permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your command syntax. In your command

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/my/working/folder -- 'npm run start'
```

`gnome-terminal` is looking for an executable with the name 'npm run start'. Such executable does not exist on your system.

Remove the quotes, and gnome-terminal will search for the executable `npm` and pass `run` and `start` as arguments.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/my/working/folder -- npm run start
```